# How to parse in Google Sheets a nested JSON structure with fallback when the data isn't available?

Tags: json, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm getting Yahoo Finance data as a JSON file (via the YahooFinancials python API) and I would like to be able to parse the data in a smart way to feed my Google Sheet.

For this example, I'm interested in getting the "cash" variable under the "date" nested structure. But as you'll see, sometimes there is no "cash" variable under the first date, so I would like the script/formula to go and get the "cash" variable that's under the second date structure.

Here is sample 1 of JSON code:

```
{ "balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly": {
        "ABBV": [
            {
                "2018-12-31": {
                    "totalStockholderEquity": -2921000000,
                    "netTangibleAssets": -45264000000
                }
            },
            {
                "2018-09-30": {
                    "intangibleAssets": 26625000000,
                    "capitalSurplus": 14680000000,
                    "totalLiab": 69085000000,
                    "totalStockholderEquity": -2921000000,
                    "otherCurrentLiab": 378000000,
                    "totalAssets": 66164000000,
                    "commonStock": 18000000,
                    "otherCurrentAssets": 112000000,
                    "retainedEarnings": 6789000000,
                    "otherLiab": 16511000000,
                    "goodWill": 15718000000,
                    "treasuryStock": -24408000000,
                    "otherAssets": 943000000,
                    "cash": 8015000000,
                    "totalCurrentLiabilities": 15387000000,
                    "shortLongTermDebt": 1026000000,
                    "otherStockholderEquity": -2559000000,
                    "propertyPlantEquipment": 2950000000,
                    "totalCurrentAssets": 18465000000,
                    "longTermInvestments": 1463000000,
                    "netTangibleAssets": -45264000000,
                    "shortTermInvestments": 770000000,
                    "netReceivables": 5780000000,
                    "longTermDebt": 37187000000,
                    "inventory": 1786000000,
                    "accountsPayable": 10981000000
                }
            },
            {
                "2018-06-30": {
                    "intangibleAssets": 26903000000,
                    "capitalSurplus": 14596000000,
                    "totalLiab": 65016000000,
                    "totalStockholderEquity": -3375000000,
                    "otherCurrentLiab": 350000000,
                    "totalAssets": 61641000000,
                    "commonStock": 18000000,
                    "otherCurrentAssets": 128000000,
                    "retainedEarnings": 5495000000,
                    "otherLiab": 16576000000,
                    "goodWill": 15692000000,
                    "treasuryStock": -23484000000,
                    "otherAssets": 909000000,
                    "cash": 3547000000,
                    "totalCurrentLiabilities": 17224000000,
                    "shortLongTermDebt": 3026000000,
                    "otherStockholderEquity": -2639000000,
                    "propertyPlantEquipment": 2787000000,
                    "totalCurrentAssets": 13845000000,
                    "longTermInvestments": 1505000000,
                    "netTangibleAssets": -45970000000,
                    "shortTermInvestments": 196000000,
                    "netReceivables": 5793000000,
                    "longTermDebt": 31216000000,
                    "inventory": 1580000000,
                    "accountsPayable": 10337000000
                }
            },
            {
                "2018-03-31": {
                    "intangibleAssets": 27230000000,
                    "capitalSurplus": 14519000000,
                    "totalLiab": 65789000000,
                    "totalStockholderEquity": 3553000000,
                    "otherCurrentLiab": 125000000,
                    "totalAssets": 69342000000,
                    "commonStock": 18000000,
                    "otherCurrentAssets": 17000000,
                    "retainedEarnings": 4977000000,
                    "otherLiab": 17250000000,
                    "goodWill": 15880000000,
                    "treasuryStock": -15961000000,
                    "otherAssets": 903000000,
                    "cash": 9007000000,
                    "totalCurrentLiabilities": 17058000000,
                    "shortLongTermDebt": 6024000000,
                    "otherStockholderEquity": -2630000000,
                    "propertyPlantEquipment": 2828000000,
                    "totalCurrentAssets": 20444000000,
                    "longTermInvestments": 2057000000,
                    "netTangibleAssets": -39557000000,
                    "shortTermInvestments": 467000000,
                    "netReceivables": 5841000000,
                    "longTermDebt": 31481000000,
                    "inventory": 1738000000,
                    "accountsPayable": 10542000000
                }
            }
        ]
}
}
```

The first date structure (under 2018-12-31) doesn't contain the cash variable. So I would like the Google sheet to go and search for the same data in 2018-09-30 and if not available go and search in 2018-06-30.
OR just scan the nested structure dates and fetch the first "cash" occurrence that will be found.

Basically, I would like to know how to skip the name of the date variable (i.e.2018-12-31) as it doesn't really matter, and just make the formula seek for the first available "cash" variable.

Main questions recap

- How to skip mentioning an exact nested level name and scan what's
  inside?
- How to keep scanning until you find the desired variable with
  a value that is not "null" (this can happen)?
- What would be the entire formula to achieve the following logic: Scan the JSON file until you find the value > if no value found, fallback to this IMPORTXML function that calls an external API.

Let me know if you need more context about the issue and thanks in advance for your help :)

EDIT: this is the `IMPORTJSON` formula I use in the cell of the spreadsheet right now.

```
=ImportJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8mxvi", "/financial/balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly/ABBV/2018-31-12/cash", "noHeaders")
```

Obviously, this one returns an error as there is nothing under that date. The JSON is also the valid link I use just now.

[image: screenshot of the Google Sheet]

Comment: is that in one cell or multiple cells?

Comment: It would be to have the number in one cell only. I'm using IMPORTJSON to get the data in the cell. I'll edit and add this to the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ","&CHAR(10), "×"), "×")), 
 ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&"cash"&"*",
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ","&CHAR(10), "×"), "×"))))), ": (.+)")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(
 TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8mxvi")), ","&CHAR(10), "×"), "×")), 
 ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&"cash"&"*", TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(
 TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8mxvi")), ","&CHAR(10), "×"), "×"))))),
  ":(.+)"), ",", "")), 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: try: `=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, ","&CHAR(10), "×"), "×")), 
 ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&"cash"&"*",
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, ","&CHAR(10), "×"), "×"))))), 
 ": (.+)"), ",", "")), 1, 1)`  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxchU.png

Comment: and instead of **A1:A** put your IMPORTJSON formula

Comment: It doesn't work :( This is the formula I use `=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER( TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(ImportJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8mxvi", "/financial/balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly/ABBV/", "noHeaders"), ","&CHAR(10), "×"), "×")), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&"cash"&"*", TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(ImportJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8mxvi", "/financial/balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly/ABBV/", "noHeaders"), ","&CHAR(10), "×"), "×"))))), ": (.+)"), ",", "")), 1, 1)`  I use this script for the IMPORTJSON: https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON

Comment: @DebugMeIfYouCan alright, I had a deeper look into it and found a way. answer updated (2nd formula)